# I want to import live soccer score in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to import some soccer live score in my Google spreadsheet.

I have some "code" but I have a problem: The scores appear just when the match it's over and when the match it's run, the spreadsheet shows me `#N/A`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.flashscore.ro/meci/Mgu7Kv8t/#sumar-meci";"//div[@id='content-all']//div[@class='current-result']/span[@class='scoreboard']")
```

Comment: Sorry for my english if there's some problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
=JOIN( ; IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.flashscore.ro/meci/Mgu7Kv8t/#sumar-meci";
 "//div[@class='current-result']"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Yea but there's the same problem. if the match isn't over don't work.
http://prntscr.com/nfdsad.png

Comment: @SplashDesign that won't be possible because running match is controlled by JavaScript and JS can't be imported in Google Sheets. you can check this by disabling JS for the site by clicking on the lock selecting site settings and disabling JS and reloading page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfi6F.png. also, you can see it by running this formula: `=array_constrain(IMPORTDATA("https://www.flashscore.ro/meci/SAhrAENr/#sumar-meci"),1500,10)` whereas you can notice you won't be able to find any mention of score simply because GS can't read JS.